# Using Geopy in a Jupyter notebook - my lambda query isn't functioning

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geopy

I'm using Geopy in a Jupyter Notebook and Python.  I want to retrieve latitude and longitude for street addresses.  I'd like to limit the query to Texas and the lambda code isn't working...can anybody help?  Even using "Houston, Tx" doesn't work.  The street address is "1931 Santa Rosa, Houston, Tx 77023".

```
#pip install geopy   #https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from functools import partial
import urllib.parse

geocode = lambda query: geolocator.geocode("%s, Houston, TX" % query)

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="team5")
location = geolocator.geocode("1931 Santa Rosa 77023")

print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
print(location.address)
```

The result of above is:

(30.8757886, -87.2426917)
1931, Brownsdale Loop Road, Santa Rosa County, Florida, 32565, United States

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `location = geolocator.geocode("1931 Santa Rosa 77023")` you are overriding your query assignment at the top

```py
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="team5")
geocode = lambda query: geolocator.geocode("%s, Houston, TX" % query)
print(geocode("1931 Santa Rosa 77023")) # CUSTOM QUERY
print(geolocator.geocode("1931 Santa Rosa 77023")) # WITHOUT CUSTOM QUERY
```

See the difference in output

```
None
1931, Brownsdale Loop Road, Santa Rosa County, Florida, 32565, United States
```

Note however that you can always run

```
print(geolocator.geocode("1931 Santa Rosa 77023", exactly_one=False))
```

to get a list of all available locations for a given address, and in this case it seems like the Florida one is the only one that matches your query string

This is confirmed if you run a manual search yourself using [openmaps](https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=1931%20Santa%20Rosa%2077023#map=19/30.87579/-87.24269)